# System.Security.SecurityException in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a application its working fine in my local system but when i run the same code in server its giving the exception as

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I had tried unblock security of the dll but this has not solved my problem. Please provide me a solution

Comment: It is most probably related wihth the asp.net trust level settings of the server. You need to check about trust levels of your server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: if you are using a shared hosting service.your hosting provider must be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using [`caspol.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cb6t8dtz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "file:////c:/wwwroot/intepub/MyApp/bin/*" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

Replace: `c:/wwwroot/intepub/MyApp/bin/*` with the path of your DLLs.

[Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/narahari/2010/06/03/system-security-securityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-web-aspnethostingpermission-system-version2-0-0-0-cultureneutral-publickeytokenb77a5c561934e089-failed/)